# PHP merging deeply nested arrays and summing values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a very large 330k character JSON object which contains roughly 3 levels deep of data, but in a relatively consistent format, I'm trying to merge multiple arrays together, starting with two, but could be as many as 30, and right now my attempt here to merge them doesn't appear to be adding the sum of nested arrays. Note that I do not want to add up values if they naturally can't be, e.g: strings can't be added

Here are two reports, for two different days, the user information would always be the same per day, but the nested `affiliates` and `users` arrays will be different, and may not always be in the same order.

```php
// today's report
$reportToday = [
    'currentUser' => [
        'id' => '33',
        'username' => 'Will',
        'userProfile' => [
            'id' => '2',
            'user_id' => '33',
        ]
    ],
    'report' => [
        'commission' => [
            'total' => [
                'commission' => 1001,
                'profit' => 40,
                'sessions_total' => 200
            ],
            'users' => [
                'rob@gmail.com' => [
                    'commission' => 500.50,
                    'profit' => 20,
                    'sessions_total' => 100,
                    'affiliates' => [
                        'abc' => [
                            'commission' => 250.25,
                            'profit' => 10,
                            'sessions_total' => 50
                        ],
                        'xyz' => [
                            'commission' => 250.25,
                            'profit' => 10,
                            'sessions_total' => 50
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'joe@gmail.com' => [
                    'commission' => 500.50,
                    'profit' => 20,
                    'sessions_total' => 100,
                    'affiliates' => [
                        'xyz' => [
                            'commission' => 250.25,
                            'profit' => 10,
                            'sessions_total' => 50
                        ],
                        'abc' => [
                            'commission' => 250.25,
                            'profit' => 10,
                            'sessions_total' => 50
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]   
    ]
];

// yesterday's report
$reportYesterday = [
    'currentUser' => [
        'id' => '33',
        'username' => 'Will',
        'userProfile' => [
            'id' => '2',
            'user_id' => '33',
        ]
    ],
    'report' => [
        'commission' => [
            'total' => [
                'commission' => 1001,
                'profit' => 40,
                'sessions_total' => 200
            ],
            'users' => [
                'joe@gmail.com' => [
                    'commission' => 500.50,
                    'profit' => 20,
                    'sessions_total' => 100,
                    'affiliates' => [
                        'abc' => [
                            'commission' => 250.25,
                            'profit' => 10,
                            'sessions_total' => 50
                        ],
                        'xyz' => [
                            'commission' => 250.25,
                            'profit' => 10,
                            'sessions_total' => 50
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'rob@gmail.com' => [
                    'commission' => 500.50,
                    'profit' => 20,
                    'sessions_total' => 100,
                    'affiliates' => [
                        'abc' => [
                            'commission' => 250.25,
                            'profit' => 10,
                            'sessions_total' => 50
                        ],
                        'xyz' => [
                            'commission' => 250.25,
                            'profit' => 10,
                            'sessions_total' => 50
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]   
    ]
];
```

Implementing the following PHP code:

```php
$combinedReport = array();

foreach (array_keys($reportToday + $reportYesterday) as $report) {
    $sums[$report] = (isset($reportToday[$report]) ? $reportToday[$report] : 0) + (isset($reportYesterday) ? $reportYesterday[$report] : 0);
}

var_dump($combinedReport);
```

Returns an empty array.

The desired output must be a combined report retaining the integrity of the data:

```php
// what I need combined
$combined = [
    'currentUser' => [
        'id' => '33',
        'username' => 'Will',
        'userProfile' => [
            'id' => '2',
            'user_id' => '33',
        ]
    ],
    'report' => [
        'commission' => [
            'total' => [
                'commission' => 2002,
                'profit' => 80,
                'sessions_total' => 400
            ],
            'users' => [
                'joe@gmail.com' => [
                    'commission' => 1001,
                    'profit' => 40,
                    'sessions_total' => 200,
                    'affiliates' => [
                        'abc' => [
                            'commission' => 500.50,
                            'profit' => 20,
                            'sessions_total' => 100
                        ],
                        'xyz' => [
                            'commission' => 500.50,
                            'profit' => 20,
                            'sessions_total' => 100
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'rob@gmail.com' => [
                    'commission' => 1001,
                    'profit' => 40,
                    'sessions_total' => 200,
                    'affiliates' => [
                        'abc' => [
                            'commission' => 500.50,
                            'profit' => 20,
                            'sessions_total' => 100
                        ],
                        'xyz' => [
                            'commission' => 250.25,
                            'profit' => 20,
                            'sessions_total' => 100
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]   
    ]
];
```

Comment: Please add what exact result you _do_ want to get, based on that shown input data.

Comment: _"Note that I do not want to add up values if they naturally can't be, e.g: strings can't be added"_ - well then you should probably check for the opposite first, before you attempt the addition - check if the values _are_ numeric.

Comment: @CBroe Ok, no worries, but in example above nested arrays aren't being calculated. Could you please provide some insight on this instead of quoting my own words :)

Comment: And to perform this not only for the elements directly at the top level, but for the nested ones deeper down as well, you will need some sort of recursive solution (unless you want to write nested loops for a maximum depths of 3 yourself.)

Comment: I'll update my stackoverflow question with the full input and exact data.